# Editing a site built with TYPO3 - Where are the content files?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, typo3

I have been asked to edit some content on a website built with TYPO3.  I have no knowledge whatsoever of TYPO3 - in fact, I had never heard of it before. I build websites from scratch with html & CSS, and know very little about sites built via CMS platforms.

I downloaded the entire site in question in order to edit various parts of content locally, only to find out that it was built entirely with this particular CMS and that I understand NOTHING about the site structure !!! I can't even locate the main index.html / index.php file nor any main CSS files....

Can anyone who understands both the TYPO3 system and basic html & CSS please enlighten me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To edit content, you'll need a login to the Typo3 backend. The login is usually at www.example.com/typo3. Ask the site owner for an account.

Once logged in, editing page content should be relatively intuitive. You can browse the site tree and edit individual content elements. There are many basic tutorials out there, like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqmo5zKM4Hc) for example. Changes to the layout are much more tricky.

Comment: Thanks, the log in info is really helpful. 
The idea is to redesign the site completely at some point, guess I'll have to start from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 stores content in the database, CSS you can find easily checking its path with the browser...

Anyway, sorry to say that but... leave it, TYPO3 is very complicated system and you can cause fatal damages which you won't be able to revert.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @biesior.  Unfortunately, I can't just leave it. I really need to get to that content !